# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop not automatically renewing DHCP lease

Tags: networking, 14.04, dhcp

Sometimes my laptops networking just stops. I fix it by doing

```
sudo ifdown em1
sudo ifup em1
```

The strange thing is, in previous releases and other *nix distros that usually doesnt produce an prompt that tells me the DHCP lease is being renewed.

Now it is. To renew a dhcp lease before I had to do 
  dhclient -r

But that's beside the point, which is I have to renew the lease manually. This is not normal behavior. How can I fix this?